# Disable "Search Photos" Lens shortcut (Super+C) and Assign to Shutter

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 13.04, lenses, shutter

I used to use Super+C to take a screenshot with Shutter. After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, I have found the Super+C shortcut to be mapped to a "Search Photos" lens. I tried going through Compiz (and Google), but I haven't found a solution yet. Is there anyway to remove this shortcut? I've tried setting it in Shutter, but it won't override Unity.

Comment: I've tried this fix: http://ubuntu-answers.blogspot.com/2012/05/change-dash-lens-hotkey.html. My Photo Lens no longer appears, but I still can't get shutter to work with <Super>c.

Comment: Solved the problem. It seems that it was a two part problem. Needed to disable the lens (comment above), and add a custom shortcut via the Keyboard settings: http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/set-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool/.

Comment: Can you add an answer to your question?

Comment: @Seth Will do. Apparently new users have to wait 8 hours before answering their own question. I'll answer it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by combining two solutions I found online

1. [Change Dash Lens Hotkeys](http://ubuntu-answers.blogspot.com/2012/05/change-dash-lens-hotkey.html)
2. [Shutter as Default](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/set-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool/)

Steps to Solve:

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter the command: `sudo gedit /usr/share/unity/lenses/photos/photos.lens`
3. Scroll to the bottom of this file and change `Shortcut=c` to `Shortcut=` (or if you do use the Photo Lens, you can set it equal to another letter)
4. Save and close gedit
5. Enter the command: `setsid unity`
6. Open the Keyboard settings (type `Keyboard` in dash)
7. Select **Shortcuts** tab.
8. Select bottom left option for **Custom Shortcuts**
9. Click the **+** button to add new shortcut
10. Enter details, Name: **Shutter Selection**, Command: **shutter -s**, Click Apply
11. Click `Disabled` and enter your desired shortcut (Super+C) in my case.
12. Close Keyboard Settings.
13. Log out and log back in.

Note: **shutter -s** is to take a selection screen grab, you may want another option, check shutter help to determine what flag you want.