# Rebind Super+C shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcuts, lenses

I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Can I rebind the Super+C (search photos) shortcut somehow? I uninstalled the photo lens, but the Launcher keeps opening with "Search photos".

The way described here:

[Disable "Search Photos" Lens shortcut (Super+C) and Assign to Shutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291649/disable-search-photos-lens-shortcut-superc-and-assign-to-shutter)

does not work because there is no /usr/share/unity/lenses/photos/photos.lens file. Can the shortcut be changed somewhere else or is it hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to delete the `Super` key binding, which is used to open the dash. I think the search lens is bound to `<whatever opens the dash>+C` so that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Ubuntu 16, the lens files `/usr/share/unity/lenses/*/*.lens` have been moved, and are now called scopes: `/usr/share/unity/scopes/*.scope`. Especially, the file one can modify to remove the Super+c shortcut is:

```
/usr/share/unity/scopes/photos.scope
```

You can list all scope files assigning shortcuts with the command:

```
grep -i 'Shortcut=' -R '/usr/share/unity/scopes/'
```